# How do i make a listing page of custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

So i made a function which makes a custom post type named Blogs. The Blogs is used to:

1. All Blogs
2. Add New Blog
3. Blog Categories

This is my function

```
function blog_post() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Blogs', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Blog', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New Blog', 'blog' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Blogs' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Blog' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Blog' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Blogs' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Blog' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Blogs' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No blog found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No blog found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Blogs'
     );

      $args = array(
          'labels'        => $labels,
          'description'   => 'Holds blogs and blog specific data',
          'public'        => true,
          'menu_position' => 5,
          'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt',      'comments' ),
          'has_archive'   => true,
      );
     register_post_type( 'blogs', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'blog_post' );

function blog_categories() {
     $labels = array(
          'name'              => _x( 'Blog Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
          'singular_name'     => _x( 'Blog Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
          'search_items'      => __( 'Search Blog Categories' ),
          'all_items'         => __( 'All Blogs Categories' ),
          'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Blog Category' ),
          'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Blog Category:' ),
          'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Blog Category' ), 
          'update_item'       => __( 'Update Blog Category' ),
          'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Blog Category' ),
          'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Blog Category' ),
          'menu_name'         => __( 'Blog Categories' ),
      );
     $args = array(
          'labels' => $labels,
          'hierarchical' => true,
     );
     register_taxonomy( 'categories', 'blogs', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'blog_categories', 0 );
```

This function defines my Blog custom post type.

So now i want a listing page for all the categories I have. How do I achieve that, any hint please?

Comment: The page is generated automatically at `/blogs/`.

Answer (score -1):

should create a template call blog.php 
then inside this file  put this comemment

## /*
Template Name: Blog - wherever you want write

*/

copy page.php content  here  or do wherever  you want

?>

then go to wb interface create a new page named Blog  and chose your blog template